# SQL Order by date but need max and min value with time occured. I need minTime minValue maxTime maxValue by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple database with radiation readings from the PRM-8000. I can load all of values into the database. What I can't do is get the max and min values at each time per day. I've seen examples where people use first and last value in groups but it isn't working with my set.

My table:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| r_time     | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| r_date     | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| r_value    | mediumint(9) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| r_label    | char(3)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| r_location | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can get MIN and MAX values per date just fine:

```
select r_date, MIN(r_value), MAX(r_value) FROM readings GROUP BY r_date;

+------------+--------------+--------------+
| r_date     | MIN(r_value) | MAX(r_value) |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2016-01-20 |            0 |           22 |
| 2016-01-21 |            0 |           26 |
| 2016-01-22 |            3 |           23 |
| 2016-01-23 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-01-24 |            2 |           24 |
| 2016-01-25 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-01-26 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-01-27 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-01-28 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-01-29 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-01-30 |            2 |           22 |
| 2016-01-31 |            1 |           25 |
| 2016-02-01 |            3 |           23 |
| 2016-02-02 |            3 |           23 |
| 2016-02-03 |            3 |           23 |
| 2016-02-04 |            2 |           24 |
| 2016-02-05 |            2 |           22 |
| 2016-02-06 |            2 |           22 |
| 2016-02-07 |            3 |           25 |
| 2016-02-08 |            2 |           22 |
| 2016-02-09 |            3 |           21 |
| 2016-02-10 |            2 |           22 |
| 2016-02-11 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-02-12 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-02-13 |            2 |           24 |
| 2016-02-14 |            2 |           26 |
| 2016-02-15 |            3 |           24 |
| 2016-02-16 |            0 |           23 |
| 2016-02-17 |            3 |           24 |
| 2016-02-18 |            2 |           29 |
| 2016-02-19 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-02-20 |            2 |           24 |
| 2016-02-21 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-02-22 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-02-23 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-02-24 |            2 |           24 |
| 2016-02-25 |            1 |           23 |
| 2016-02-26 |            2 |           23 |
| 2016-05-27 |            7 |           12 |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

However I can't get the times the mins and max's occured. I have removed duplicate lines for readings, and as far as I understand with MySQL, I need to partiton by date and get the min and max. Any ideas? This is the kind of query someone would use to get the min and max temperature which occurred at each time at each day.Do I need to JOIN from two tables with max and min or else something?

Here is some sample data for one day:

```
    +-------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
    | Id    | r_time   | r_date     | r_value | r_label | r_location |
    +-------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
    | 40892 | 04:46:00 | 2016-02-18 |      29 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 40838 | 03:52:00 | 2016-02-18 |      25 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 41309 | 11:43:00 | 2016-02-18 |      23 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 41524 | 15:18:00 | 2016-02-18 |      22 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 41176 | 09:30:00 | 2016-02-18 |      21 | CPM     | NULL       |
    +-------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------------+

    +-------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
    | Id    | r_time   | r_date     | r_value | r_label | r_location |
    +-------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
    | 41343 | 12:17:00 | 2016-02-18 |       2 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 40698 | 01:32:00 | 2016-02-18 |       2 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 40694 | 01:28:00 | 2016-02-18 |       3 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 41308 | 11:42:00 | 2016-02-18 |       3 | CPM     | NULL       |
    | 41315 | 11:49:00 | 2016-02-18 |       3 | CPM     | NULL       |
    +-------+----------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
```

And this is a sample output which provides the date, minimum radiation value with time recorded, and then the maximum radiation value with time recorded.

```
+------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| r_date     | maxval | maxtime  | minval | mintime  |
+------------+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| 2016-01-20 |     22 | 19:48:00 |      0 | 18:45:00 |
| 2016-01-20 |     22 | 19:48:00 |      0 | 18:47:00 |
| 2016-01-21 |     26 | 17:42:00 |      0 | 18:18:00 |
| 2016-01-22 |     23 | 05:56:00 |      3 | 05:14:00 |
| 2016-01-22 |     23 | 05:56:00 |      3 | 08:39:00 |
| 2016-01-22 |     23 | 05:56:00 |      3 | 17:08:00 |
| 2016-01-22 |     23 | 05:56:00 |      3 | 17:45:00 |
| 2016-01-22 |     23 | 05:56:00 |      3 | 21:02:00 |
```

Comment: What if the min or max value occurred at multiple times the same day, which time should this return?

Comment: Starting data and desired outcome would help (although we don't need such a large set).  Do you just want to add a grouping by the time as well (`GROUP BY r_date, r_time`)?  Or is it you're trying to find the time-of-day the maximum/minimum values occurred (which will obviously be different...), which would be a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.

Comment: Also, multiple min and max values could occur at multiple times. The radiation device records at each minute interval.

Comment: Outcome is simple: date, minTime, minValue, maxTime, maxValue

Comment: Ben, I have noticed this and I'm expecting when the sun is not around, it oculd happen multiple times a day. The hours around midnight and the hours around noon.

Comment: Maybe my table needs an AM and PM flag

Comment: With that flag I can group not just among the date but the part of day.

Comment: I'm going to need a FLAG to separate the time of day. low and max readings can occur multiple times a day. So select the lowest of each day with that reading and the highest of each day with that reading

Comment: show some sample data from the table and how the output should be

Comment: You don't need an am/pm flag. `03:52:00` is am; `15:18:00` is pm; it's implicit. But it is still unclear what you really want. You are showing `MIN(r_value)` and `MAX(r_value), but are you actually interested in them? Or are you only interested in  `MIN(r_time)` and its corresponding `r_value` and `MAX(r_time)` and its corresponding `r_value`?

Comment: Downvoted for your comment reply "I'd probably not hire you". We have a policy of '[Be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)' here!

Comment: @vkp, you are correct, and I don't need that. I think the query is working as it should. Since I want to know the minimum and maximum values each day, I"ll get each time the max and min occurred.

Answer (score 1):

To get the max and min value per day and the corresponding time they occurred, use

```
select t.r_date,t.maxval,rmax.r_time maxtime,t.minval,rmin.r_time mintime
from (select r_date, max(r_value) maxval, min(r_value) minval
      from readings
      group by r_date) t
join readings rmax on rmax.r_date = t.r_date and t.maxval = rmax.r_value
join readings rmin on rmin.r_date = t.r_date and t.minval = rmin.r_value
```

To get the max and min values at each time per day just group by date and time

```
select r_date, r_time, max(r_value) maxval, min(r_value) minval
from readings
group by r_date, r_time
```

Comment: This is a good answer if the min and max values are unique per r_date. But by OP's own admission, it can happen. That's where it gets tricky.

Comment: i think this would give all the times the min and max values occurred in a day @sstan

Comment: @sstan.. i see what you are saying. but the question is ambiguous, at one place the op says he needs max and min values at each time per day..at the other it seems like saying times when the max and min values occurred for each day.

Comment: I as the OP understand now from my data that the min and max values occur more than once a day. But the answer given is adequate. I need more columns to seperate the data. Thank you for the response. At my work place I don't have peers to help with issues like this. Very much appreciated. I do have a background in linux since Slackware 3, but I do need help sometimes. This is for my own project at home. I like to enhance my skills.

Comment: If you use t.r_date, min(rmax.r_value) maxtemp, min(rmax.r_time) maxtime, min(rmin.r_value) mintemp, min(rmin.r_time) mintime, you will get the lowest and highest temperatures for the day together with the first time that the minimum or maximum occurs.  That means only row per date.

Answer (score -1):

I took a look at the manual, and MySQL lacks first and last aggregate operators.  If I had to deal with a problem like this, I would probably sort by date and then JDBC to read the rows into a Java program.  The Java program would then start finding minimum and maximum temperature rows for each date.

Another choice would be to create a new column where the values are a concatenation of the temperature and the time.  The temperature would have to be zero padded so that all of the values would line up with the same number of characters before and after the decimal points.  Find the min and max values of this column for each date, and the results will have both the temperature and time.

Comment: @Bradley - Broadly, this falls into the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] class of problems, for which there are solutions in MySQL (although yes, not having windowing functions makes it less than ideal).  In the general case, an SQL-only approach is likely to outperform a client application needing to make multiple trips to the database.  The concatenation idea would work (so long as it was in that order - `temperature`, then `time`), but I'm not sure it would really be that more performant.  Oh, and maintaining a formatted column is a nightmare, which is why you're not supposed to do it.